# Processing at index level

Tags: influxdb

Is it possible to insert a processing at the indexing in influxDB ?
More precisely I try to split the value of a tag into several tags ..

Typically, I will need to transform a tag in input like this :

> Tag:toto_tata_titi

into this :

> Tag1: Toto, Tag2: tata, Tag3: titi

Comment: If I am not wrong, what you are looking for is, continuous queries. https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/query_language/continuous_queries/ did you explore it?

Comment: Not possible in the DB. Best to split the tags at client level before sending to DB. If the client absolutely cannot be changed, could make a proxy to modify data before forwarding on to the DB.